# issue regarding "Unrelease game" in public beta versus legal implications

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, legal

A meta post I seen a while ago argued that a question should not be closed in regards to asking about a game that has not been released, if the game in question is accessible.

This mostly concerned games that are in beta testing, where the game in question is publicly tested, and it would be feasible for somebody else to be able to answer given knowledge and understand they have from having played the game as far as the developer allows in said beta testing.

I signed up for the Battleborne beta, recently, and part of the conditions in which I was allowed access was that I would not disclose any information about the game.

From my experience, this is common in any form of early testing. As the player, one of the conditions in which you are given access to this early model of the game is that you will not disclose how the game works to people outside of the beta.

How do we feel about asking/ answering questions that involve providing information from experience where the initial agreement prohibits our disclosure of said information?

Comment: had difficulty finding the meta, so would appreciate if anyone could source it. I know it was by one of our high-level users

Comment: If you can play it, you can ask about it. It's not up to us to enforce NDA's, so if you want to risk it, ask away.

Comment: @Frank, NDA has as much legal grounds as piracy, in some countries. You can not say "we accept this illegal practice, but we don't accept that practice becaue it is illegal". That is called being hypocritical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're not in the business of enforcing NDA's *per se*.

However, in general, when there is a question as to whether to consider a game 'unreleased', versus 'generally availiable', we have *often* used the existence as an NDA as a close-enough heuristic to consider questions about a game to not be a good fit here at Arqade.

Comment: I have seen the exact opposite argued, where users have stated "its in closed beta, only a select group has access, but it is still accessible". Under those grounds, I have seen questions reopened. I think I need to find that meta for clarification.